# python3 doesn't execute getbootstrap html code

Tags: html, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap

If i run the following code (extract from carousel template in getbootstrap) from a browser it is executed successfully:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0052)https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/carousel/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.8.5">
    <title>Carousel Template · Bootstrap</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://xxxxx/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jumbotron.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./Carousel Template · Bootstrap_files/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <!--header-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand">XXXXXXX</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="signin.html">Sign In</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="register.html">Register</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="signin.html">Sign In</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/carousel/#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
<!--/header-->

</body>
</html>
```

As i replace all href with `{{ url_for('static',filename='javascript name or css name')}}` 
and invoke the page with `render_template('testnewhome.html')`

I don't get any error in wsgi but look and feel is really different.

Just the let you understand:
html code executed from browser looks this way
[good looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoGdo.png)

If i run it from python it looks this way

[bad looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaXmL.png)

Any clue? I m really stuck

Comment: Have you examined the HTML source of each page? It looks like the path to the CSS is incorrect. The best way to determine that is to look at the HTML source itself.

Comment: there is only one page, i checked it out carefully. why do you say path to css is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's sorted. There was no problem with the code, you can use it as a reference.
I simply removed all css files from ccs folder and copied them over. It looks like the getbootstrap ditribution files are not good. So i suggest to everyone to download a working page and use the downloaded css and js to create a new page.

HIH